# Find $\vec{QB}$ in terms of $\mathbf c$

Tags: analytic-geometry, affine-geometry, vectors

[image]

I've managed to work out “$\vec{AM}$ in terms of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$” to be $3\mathbf a+\mathbf b$.

But how can I work out “$\vec{QB}$ in terms of $\mathbf c$”?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** find $\vec{AB}$ in terms of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, then find $\vec{AQ}$ in terms of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$.  Also find $\vec{AM}$ in terms of $\vec{AQ}$.